# What happened with Dolores 'core' after Charlotte Hale took it from the lab while escaping?

Tags: westworld-tv

In Westworld S03E06, we see that Charlotte Hale, which became another avatar of Dolores, stole from the Serac lab a pearl (that damaged white sphere - "core" - containing the memories and identity *of the original Dolores Abernathy*), in the last moment when she tries to escape from the agents of Serac which are hunting her.

Wikipedia says about this **Episode 6** that:

> In her escape from Serac, [Charlotte] destroys Hector's core **and takes the Dolores core**.

but also does not explain what happened with that core in just a few seconds time.

**What happened with Dolores 'core' after Charlotte Hale took it from the lab while escaping?**

Fact is that when the agents attack her, just moments later, Charlotte put her phone on the floor and activate the giant robot meant to deal with riots control - *then raise her hands* - but no sign of the Dolores core on her whatsoever at that moment. As the filming was made, from around Charlotte, we cannot see anywhere a place where she could keep on her (or hide ??) the Dolores "pearl" - having about the size of an apple.

However, we cannot see any moment when Charlotte is alone while running, as the agents keep shooting at her while hunting her on the stairs of the lab, so she cannot hide anywhere the pearl of Dolores far from their sight. She simply seems to not have anymore on her the pearl in the seconds when she went outside of the lab. I watched several times this episode just because of this strange detail about Dolores' pearl missing, but couldn't see anytime something to explain this fact.

**Later edit:**

Please explain if you think that thing could be due to any *continuity break* happened as in more other movies (where a scene is shot in multiple locations, or in different days, even in inverse order of the movie events).

My opinion is that such continuity break couldn't be a real explanation - because the central point of hunting Charlotte was exactly because she stole that core. *After all, Dolores was the robot that would do everything to destroy Serac so she had to be stopped by all means by her enemy.*

Comment: Don't take it personally; I don't think anyone is targetting your questions. You're asking about events that weren't shown / future seasons. Since it's just speculation at the moment there's no way to answer correctly / objectively, thus (I assume) the downvotes. We won't know the answer until Season 4 is out.

Comment: @Luciano, you entirely missed the point. I didn't ask a question 'about Season 4', I just reminded everyone what already happened in Season 3. Everyone can go on HBOGO or elsewhere and see again that episode. I didn't ask what will happen to that core of Dolores on Season 4, my question was **what - already - happened to Dolores core during that same Season 3, during that 10 seconds time when we had our eyes on the screen and saw all the action unfolding**. I hope it is clear now. Btw, downvoting is a coward behaviour when one say nothing at all (people have and use words, only animals don't).

Comment: @Eve, because the show is ongoing MYSTERY series, there are constantly questions that can't or will not be answered until later seasons (and maybe not ever). I don't think it's fair to just downvote for that, all time, especially when sometimes, the EPs do hint or point blank explain something either during the season or right after the season is over. I'm going to upvote you, because you took a good deal of time trying to explain it and because most likely season 4 will answer it, even though it will be a while.

Comment: as DarthLocke said. I also believe your last edit makes the question _even more_ speculative, I'd remove the whole "would be / could happen / might need" part, it detracts from the core of your question.

Comment: @Eve: I tried to edit the question to make it shorter and more focused. I think it could be made even shorter, but I forgot the details of the episode. However, I don't really understand why it is not simply a mistake: Charlotte probably still has the core but the crew forgot to show it in the scene. Nothing out of ordinary.

Comment: @Taladris, _your edit removed few essential parts, pls reinstate the old form_. During same sequence Charlotte just destroyed another core - of Hector, the lover of Maeve - the ally of Serac at that time (while she had a word fight with Dolores, in the digital realm of course, so Maeve went crazy about that, seeing what happens). Removing the core of Dolores, Charlotte saved her from the angry of Maeve. I can't stress enough that Charlotte couldn't hide that original core of Dolores. Soldiers were hunting after the core too, as one can imagine. Both were Dolores, _both the core and Charlotte_.

Comment: @Eve: I am not sure what essential parts I removed. I don't think the plotlines of Bernard, Maeve,... have any bearing on the question.

Comment: @Taladris while _Maeve was the "tool" used to hunt Dolores in the digital world, on the real one Serac hunted her avatars and her "incarnation" by himself_. Maybe I'll even put this thing also on my post, too, to make everything clearer to the readers.Of course, I can't avoid disclosing the so-named spoilers, however it's about a movie already broadcasted (not some future episode) so I assume people who didn't watch it won't read this question either. _I would thus greatly appreciate people not trying to comment, vote or edit my post if they don't recall the core details of this great movie_.

Comment: @Eve: do whatever you want with the question. I am out of it :)

Comment: @Eve, I share your opinion on downvoters. I have reviewed this many times and understand why these responses are irritating. You are simply asking why does Hale appear to grab the damaged pearl and then in the very next scene she is not holding the damaged pearl. It could be a simple edit continuity error or maybe the damaged pearl is only lifted and discarded immediately by Hale and the lifting of it off of its dock was to portray the disconnection to the Dolores Host being questioned by Maeve and Hector it crashes once unplugged by Hale.Thats all I got my photos will not upload.

Answer (score -1):

Halores passed [Joanna](https://westworld.fandom.com/wiki/Joanna) the damaged/encrypted pearl.

She is close to Halores and is the only character that speaks against Serac's intention of destroying all Delos assets seemingly siding her with Halores and although she is present in the room prior to the Halores gas attack she is not among the dead bodies at the table.

Yes the damaged/encrypted pearl containing the secret gathered Westworld data is way too important. Overlooking its location seems impossible even through edit continuity error.

The central reason for hunting Hale is not the damaged/encrypted core because Serac already has the damaged/encrypted core recovered from Collins, he just cannot access it because Dolores has encrypted control.

Halores is tapping the security feed when she spots Maeve and 3 other helpers to be printed in the Delos lab. The final core is encrypted by Dolores and highlighted blue and labeled network attached host control- unable to identify host.This prompts Halores to call someone, presumably Dolores, and said, *"the tracker in our friends blood paid off I have the location you are looking for but we have a f****** problem they recovered Connells pearl"* referring to Martin Connells whom Dolores killed and replaced. So Halores actually says Serac already has the damaged/encrypted pearl. Serac tells Halores (whom he thinks is Hale) the only thing I want out of this place is what you promised me the encryption key which apparently I'm going to have to retreive myself referring to him realizing Hale can't help him he using Maeve and freinds will have to capture Dolores and take encryption key by force. His goal is the secret data collected at Westworld which will be accessed w the encryption key to fix the outliers like his brother in Rehoboam.

Comment: And You Film Bolg, this might make for a pretty good answer, but do have a source (even episode number, dialogue/transcript. Is that quote, an official quote? If so, what episode?) or a screencap to help back up that Joanna had it. Her Westworld Wiki Fan page doesn't say as much.